# with...there is associated

Tags: grammaticality

Is it correct to write in a scientific paper

"With every Hermitian metric there is associated a real vector space"?

This is the version I prefer, but some might say

"With every Hermitian metric is associated a real vector space".

One can also say

"A real vector space is associated with every Hermitian metric"

but the emphasis is not laid on "with every Hermitian metric" in that case.

Which of the first two constructions is better? Do you have a different suggestion?

Many thanks,
Dan

Comment: For every Hermitian metric there is an associated real vector space.

Answer (score 1):

In this situation, you would write it as 'With every Hermitian metric, there is a real vector space associated with it.' This would keep the focus on the Hermitian Metric whilst also keeping the sentence from sounding disjointed.

Hope this helps,

Ethan.

Comment: Thanks Ethan! Wouldn't it be better to say 'For every Hermitian metric, there is a real vector space associated with it.' If you have to say more things about that real vector space, the reader might get confused by 'associated with it', which comes in too late and they may have forgotten with what that vector space is associated. What is wrong with the first two versions proposed?